# Sending array between server and client via Meteor.methods using angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get an array to be managed by my server and shared across to my client. I figured that the Meteor.methods() would be the way to do it by creating a getter method.
Though for some reason it prints to console correctly by the server but returns undefined to the client when I do the Meteor.call()
I get the undefined returns regardless of whether the if is true or false, It's always undefined.

```
///server
Meteor.methods({
  createNewUser: this.createNewUser,
  getRoles: this.getRoles
});
...
getRoles(id) { 
  console.log(roles);
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(id, "admin")) {
    return roles;
  } else {
    return 'blah';
  }
}

///client
ngOnInit() {
 MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
 ...

    Meteor.call("getRoles", Meteor.userId(), (data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      this.roles = data;
      console.log("roles", this.roles);
    });

    console.log("user list", this.userList);
    console.log("roles", this.roles);
....
});
```

The other method in the Meteor.methods() works perfectly and I can't seem to work out why this one doesn't seeing as it does so much less.

```
///output
demo.component.ts:53 user list []
demo.component.ts:54 roles []
demo.component.ts:53 user list [Object]
demo.component.ts:54 roles []
demo.component.ts:48 data undefined
demo.component.ts:50 roles undefined
demo.component.ts:48 data undefined
demo.component.ts:50 roles undefined
demo.component.ts:53 user list [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
demo.component.ts:54 roles undefined
demo.component.ts:48 data undefined
demo.component.ts:50 roles undefined
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tried converting the returns from the server into JSON also and still get undefined back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was in the Method.call()

It returns an error and a result, rather than a single object.

```
    ///client
    Meteor.call("getRoles", Meteor.userId(), (error, data) => {
      if (!error) {
        console.log("data", data);
        this.roles = data;
        console.log("roles", this.roles);
      } else {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      }
    });

    ///output
demo.component.ts:57 user list []
demo.component.ts:58 roles []
demo.component.ts:57 user list [Object]
demo.component.ts:58 roles []
demo.component.ts:49 data ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:51 roles ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:49 data ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:51 roles ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:57 user list [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
demo.component.ts:58 roles ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:49 data ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
demo.component.ts:51 roles ["admin","spectator","coach","player"]
```

This is what I'm expecting.(though not sure why the MeteorObservable is triggered so many times.)

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.call is async, so the logging you do immediately thereafter executes before the data is returned. You already have your callback set up, you should be looking for the returned data in there.

Also, once inside the callback, be careful about the use of "this". It's probably not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I made some changes to test this also and extended my output, it still doesnt seem to have helped.
My roles on the client is initialised as [] and gets changed to undefined by the method, so it is being set, just not being set to what i want it to be.
atleast thats how it seems to me